# getting loading svg while scraping image with flutter from website?

Tags: flutter, web-scraping

I want to get the url of img from website with flutter. But when I use .attributes［'src'］for getting the image url, I get the loading svg. is there any way to get the image url not the loading svg??

Comment: what library did you use for web-scrapping?

Comment: html and http i use these libraries

Comment: i mean if the scraping action just wait until the website is completely loaded, there will be no problem. here the website is using loading svg for img while loading

Comment: so what you want is to modify the SVG to using local asset?